# DRF - How to limit depth of a serializer?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have many models and using `DRF` as a REST API.

Almost every serializer is `nested`. This causes a problem such that `ModelASerializer` is multiple times nested because it uses `ModelBSerializer` which uses `ModelCSerializer`... etc.

```
class ModelBSerializer(..):
    modelcs = ModelCSerializer(...)

    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'

class ModelASerializer(..):
    modelbs = ModelBSerializer(many=True..)

    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
```

The thing is that it obviously slows down everything. I thought that if I add `depth=2/1` to `ModelASerializer.Meta`, `modelcs` won't be serialized because they are 2/1 levels nested. But it still serializers everything. Is it possible to make it work?

I can create new serializers but this would be much more elegant.

Comment: You could create a generic field pruning meta class to selectively prune out sub-fields and sub-objects, recursively, on a given base serializers.

Comment: First of all the **`depth`** meta attribute works only with **ForeignKey** relations, not **reverse foreign key** relations. The best solutions to your problem is, Create new serializers and manage them properly.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm mistaken I believe you have a bunch of related models all nested within one another?

I think you could return an array of model IDs rather then their seriealized form. Then you could do a second call to lookup that serialized model and find it's related/nested models. So on and so forth to get your result.

I believe you can pass an additional parameter into the serializer. Using this additional parameter you can specify whether or not it should serialize a nested model; and how far it should go.

Pseudo Code

```
class ModelBSerializer(self, serialize_depth = 0):
    id = { Model B ID }
    modelcs = ModelCSerializer(..., serialize_depth - 1)

    class Meta:
        if(serialize_depth > 0):
            fields = '__all__'
        else:
            fields = ('id')

class ModelASerializer(..):
    modelbs = ModelBSerializer(many=True..., serialize_depth=2)

    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
```